# Is this the expected behavior when posting an image to a user's wall with the iOS Facebook SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following code to post to the user's wall. It works fine, but I noticed that it also created a photo album named after my app, and added the image to that album. Is this the expected behavior for an iOS app? Is there any way to just post to the wall without saving the image in the user's account?

```
FBRequestHandler handler =
^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
{
    // output the results of the request
    NSLog(@"Error - %@", error);
    NSLog(@"Result - %@", result);
};

UIImage *img = [logo getImage];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Test Message",@"message",img,@"picture",nil];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/Photos"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:handler];
```

Comment: I think you have to give permissions to your app from facebook side.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. It posts successfully, but I think maybe I'm posting the wrong thing. I don't want to add any images to the user's album. I only want to update the user's status with a picture and a message.

Comment: Try to use :
`[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:handler];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@GoldenJoe , You are using a custom application to POST an image on facebook. This way when ever you register an application you are provided with an App ID/API Key) . While POSTing an image from your iPhone application , facebook creates a separate album with the name you used to register the above mentioned application on Facebook.

This is all normal that a separate album is being create by Facebook on its own and all image that you post using that application credential (APP ID) are clubbed under the same album. You might like to give a look to the [Album](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) and [Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) to better understand the concept.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: You can post a photo to a specific existing album directly; but you’ll have to ask for additional permission `user_photos`.